# Problems with Program using openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.x, loops, openpyxl

How can I fix my code to get a result that gives me two values instead of one? My goal is to get the max E value that occurs for each group of numbers in column A. I am wanting to get a result of (1,max E), (2,Max E), etc... When I run the code, I only get values that are in column A and not both in column A and E. Any help would be appreciated. I am open to using different modules to get the result that I am wanting. If you can, explain your answer as best as you can.
File Name is Book1 using Sheet1.

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
sheet= wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for col in ws.columns:
col_max = 0
for cell in col:
    if cell.value > col_max:
        col_max = cell.value
print('next max:', col_max)
```

my result is:

```
next max: 1
next max: 2
next max: 3
next max: 4
next max: 5
```

Excel Spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: What can you not do?

Comment: When I run the code, I get values that are in column A. My goal is to get a result that is similar to (1, max E), (2, Max E), etc.., which is not happening.